# MultiQC: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

Tags: python, module, conda, imp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIROo.png)

I am running **fastqc** and **multiqc** in ubuntu linux terminal. fastqc runs perfectly without any issues but multiqc fails to run, showing the message. No idea how to fix the missing **'imp'** module. I tried to read and apply every solution found in the internet or google.

I used the command **'conda install multiqc'** to install multiqc in the existing conda environment. I tried to install it in a new conda environment. Still, its showing the same message.The **python** version currently running is **3.12.0**

Could anyone help to fix the issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python 3.12 is new and the consequences of the changes it introduces (like dropping the `imp` module) need to propagate to the community.

Stay on Python 3.11 for now.

Answer (score 3):

Issue as been reported on GitHub and should be fixed in the next version:

https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/issues/2112