# Chatterbot : wheel==0.41.3 is incompatible with wheel>=0.32.0,<0.33.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, chatbot

whenever I type

```
pip install flask spacy chatterbot chatterbot_corpus nltk SpeechRecognition pyttsx3
```

I get

```
ERROR: Some build dependencies for preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz conflict with the backend dependencies: wheel==0.41.3 is incompatible with wheel>=0.32.0,<0.33.0.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip."
```

Comment: ok im sorry ill look for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for chatterbot; here are the workarounds:

**This error message indicates that there is a dependency conflict while trying to build or install a package.**

Updating Dependency Versions: Try upgrading the installed "wheel" package to make its version range compatible with the requirements of the "preshed" package. You can use either of the following commands to attempt an update:

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

or

```
pip install wheel>=0.32.0,<0.33.0
```

---

Lowering Version Requirements: If the requirements of the "preshed" package are strict, you might consider looking for a "preshed" version that is compatible with the existing "wheel" version. You can try to install a specific version of the package using the following command:

```
pip install preshed==2.0.1
```

Check Other Dependencies: Sometimes, the dependencies of one package can conflict with dependencies of other packages. Try checking the dependencies of other relevant packages and ensure they align with the requirements of both the "preshed" and "wheel" packages.

Create a Virtual Environment: If you're using multiple packages in a project and their dependencies clash, consider creating a virtual environment. Virtual environments isolate dependencies for different projects, helping to avoid conflicts.

---

**Link to git: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/2317**

Comment: thank you realyyyyyyyyyyy very much bro

Comment: hey uhhhh whenever i try this "pip install preshed==2.0.1" i get  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for preshed
  Running setup.py clean for preshed
Failed to build preshed
ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274572/multiqc-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-imp

Comment: Imp is removed from `3.12` you have to downgrade to python `3.11`

Comment: i tried 3.11.0 version but i did not work and shows "note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip."